# Textures not showing properly in Cycles. Is there a fix to this?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Newbie here. I'm having some trouble with using Cycles, and am not sure how to fix it.

[image: Screenshots of model in Eevee vs Cycles.]

When in the 3d viewport, textures show up fine when using Eevee. When switched to Cycles, the textures seem to disappear at random spots and changes when I tab in and out of the viewport.

Where could the problem be rooted?

Comment: Can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It may be overlapping faces (it causes Z fighting), try to merge the vertices in Edit mode: press M >Mege by Distance